# Have caption run only as wide as the table on centered table

Tags: width, centering, xsl-fo, caption

I'm using XSL-FO with Antennahouse FO formatter.

How do I make the `fo:caption` in a `fo:table-and-caption` element run only as wide as the `fo:table` does?

Essentially, I am looking for the FO equivalent of this HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Image with Caption – CENTERED</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div style="border:2px solid blue;">
      <table style="border:1px solid green; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
        <caption style="caption-side:bottom; text-align:left; border:1px solid red;"><p style="font-size:9pt;">Sourceline (left edge should match up with table's left edge, and line breaking should occur at right edge of table)</p></caption>
        <tr>
          <td><p>&lt;- The table runs only this wide. -></p></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <p>BLUE = wrapper-DIV</p>
    <p>GREEN = table</p>
    <p>RED = caption</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

which looks like this: [image: HTML rendering of above code]

The XSL-FO code I have is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master margin-bottom="58px" margin-left="120px" margin-right="120px" margin-top="50px" master-name="content-page" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in">
      <fo:region-body margin-bottom="44px" margin-top="50px" region-name="xsl-region-body" />
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="content-page">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">

      <fo:block>
        <fo:table-and-caption border="2px solid blue" text-align="center">
        <fo:table-caption border="1px solid red" caption-side="bottom">
          <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="left">Sourceline (left edge should match up with table's left edge, and line breaking should occur at right edge of table)</fo:block>
        </fo:table-caption>
        <fo:table border="1px solid green">
          <fo:table-column/>
          <fo:table-body>
            <fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>&lt;- The table runs only this wide. -></fo:block>
              </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
          </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
        </fo:table-and-caption>
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>BLUE = fo:table-and-caption</fo:block>
      <fo:block>GREEN = fo:table</fo:block>
      <fo:block>RED = fo:caption</fo:block>

    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

which renders like this: [image: PDF rendering of above code]

How do I force (in XSL-FO) the table caption to only run as wide as the table (which might be arbitrarily complex, including e.g. `fo:table-footer` and table borders on table or cells), and start at the left edge of its associated table (like in the HTML rendering)?

Comment: Is is probably less appropriate from a semantic point of view, but an option could be adding a row to the table and putting the text there (spanning cells and fixing borders if needed).

Comment: Nice idea. But even if tolerating the skewed semantics and getting the border+spanning fixups right, I don't see how one would accommodate a fo:table-footer element using this technique.

Comment: I wound up using what @lfurini suggested in my case, and in a similar requirement, I was nesting the table to show (content table) in a helper table for layout. Thank you!